# Dashed Line for facet_grid in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a dashed line between facet grid ggplot2 plot.

```
data_people <- data.frame(Group = c("Good", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium",  "BAD", "BAD", "BAD", "BAD"),
                          people = c("Jonney", "Eva", "Eilse", "Doe", "Matt", "June", "Som", "Clara","Nick"),
                          number = c(0.04, 0.09, 0.10, 0.13, 0.13, 0.06, 0.05, 0.00, 0.3))
```

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstance)

ggplot(data = data_people, aes(x = number, y = people, group = Group)) +
  geom_barh(stat = "identity", colour = "black") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-0.20, 0.00, 0.20, 0.40, 0.60, 0.80, 1.00),
                     limits = c(-0.20, 1)) +
  facet_grid(Group~., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y", switch = 'y') +
  xlab(" ") +
  ylab(" ")
```

What I get is this Figure.

[image]

What I want to get is this Figure.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do this directly with ggplot, instead it's necessary to alter the grob and redraw. Adapting the excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42849195/2835261) you can do:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gtable)

p <- ggplot(data = data_people, aes(x= number, y = people, group = Group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = "black") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-0.20, 0.00, 0.20, 0.40, 0.60, 0.80, 1.00), limits = c(-0.20, 1)) +
  facet_grid(Group ~ ., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y", switch = 'y') + xlab(" ") +
  ylab(" ") +
  theme()

gt <- ggplotGrob(p)

panels <- subset(gt$layout, grepl("panel", gt$layout$name), t:r)

rows <- unique(panels$b)[-length(unique(panels$b))] + 1

g <- linesGrob(x = unit(c(0, 1), "npc"),
              y = unit(c(.5, .5), "npc"),
              gp = gpar(col = "black", lty = "dotted", lwd = 5) )

gt <- gtable_add_grob(gt, 
                      rep(list(g), length(rows)),
                      r = min(panels$r) - 1, t = rows, l = max(panels$l))

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is the closest I've got so far.

With `panel.spacing` you adjust the distance between graphs and with `panel.border` you can define the line around the graphs. If you remove `linetype = "dashed"` you get just a simple separation line which I think looks better, but it's your call.

```r
library(ggplot2)
# library(ggstance) ## unnecessary

ggplot(data = data_people, aes(x = number, y = people)) +
  geom_col(colour = "black") + 
  scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 7, limits = c(-0.20, 1)) +
  facet_grid("Group", scales = "free_y", space = "free_y", switch = 'y') +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "black", linetype = "dashed"))
```

[image]