# How to control facet height and width in plotnine?

Tags: python, ggplot2, facet, grob, plotnine

I have seen this post regarding `ggplot2`:
[How to automatically adjust the width of each facet for facet_wrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52341385/how-to-automatically-adjust-the-width-of-each-facet-for-facet-wrap)

I was wondering:

how can I achieve the same in **plotnine**? I haven't found anything similar to `grob`. I would need it for a plot that is part of a python3 pipeline so I really don't want to convert part of the code to R.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the post you linked and [proposed a far simpler solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61127086/9664796), which is to use `facet_grid` rather than `facet_wrap`.  When you use `facet_grid`, you can specify `space='free'` to automatically adjust the size of the facets, rather than the size of the scales only with `scales=`.  There does not appear to be an option with `facet_wrap` to specify `space=` (only `scales=`).

I do not have direct experience using plotnine, but [a quick check here](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/plotnine.facets.facet_grid.html) shows that there exists a similar function that includes both `space=` and `scales=` arguments.