# ggplot facet spanning on several cols

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

Is there a way to get `ggplot2::facet_wrap()` to have a facet span on several rows?

I'm thinking of something very similar to what could be achieved with `{patchwork}` ([example](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/layout.html#controlling-the-grid)).

Here is a very lame example with 3 facets:

```r
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  select(cyl, am, gear, carb) %>% pivot_longer(-cyl) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill=name, x=value)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge") +
  facet_wrap("cyl", scale="free")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

In this example, how could I have these facets on 2 rows with first `cyl==4&6` on 1 column each, and then `cyl==8` which would span on 2 columns?

Here is my expected output (beware of my mighty MS Paint skills):
[image]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52341385/how-to-automatically-adjust-the-width-of-each-facet-for-facet-wrap/52422707) may be of some help

Answer (score 3):

I've recently put up a [manual facets](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Facets.html#manual-facets-1) function in ggh4x on github. It allows you to do pretty much exactly what your expected output looks like. (disclaimer: I'm the author of ggh4x)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggh4x) # devtools::install_github("teunbrand/ggh4x")

mtcars %>% 
  select(cyl, am, gear, carb) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-cyl) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill=name, x=value)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge") +
  facet_manual("cyl", scale="free", design = matrix(c(1,3,2,3), 2, 2))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

P.S. because this facet function is new, it might have some bugs I'm unaware of. Please let me know if you find some.