# Control tick marks in ggforce::facet_row

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, x-axis, ggforce

I am trying to produce a histogram with y-axis for different subsets of the data.

I have been following the instructions from here:
[How to automatically adjust the width of each facet for facet_wrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52341385/how-to-automatically-adjust-the-width-of-each-facet-for-facet-wrap)

But I cannot seem to get the tick marks on the axis to work.

```
score <- rep(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), c(20424, 1636, 1864, 989, 397, 174, 69, 18, 4))
damage <- rep(c("No damage", "damage"), c(20424, 5151))
damage <- ordered(damage, c("No damage", "damage"))

df <- data.frame(score, damage)

library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

#The following produces the graph as I would like it but there are no ticks or tick labels
#on the x-axis

df %>%        
        ggplot(aes(x = score)) +
        geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) +
        scale_x_discrete(name = "Score") +
        scale_y_continuous(name = "") +
        ggforce::facet_row(vars(damage), scales = 'free', space = 'free')
```

[image: Plot 1]

```
##Whereas this gives me the tick marks and labels but messes up my graph

df %>%        
        ggplot(aes(x = score)) +
        geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) +
        scale_x_discrete(name = "Score",
                         limits = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)) +
        scale_y_continuous(name = "") +
        ggforce::facet_row(vars(damage), scales = 'free', space = 'free')
```

[image: Plot 2]

I have tried many permutations, with and without using the ggforce::facet_row option, but I just don't seem to be able to get it to work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `x` is continuous, not discrete. Try `scale_x_continuous(name = "Score", breaks = 0:8)`. `facet_row` can be replaced by `facet_grid(cols = vars(damage), scales = 'free', space = 'free')`, but either works.

Answer (score 0):

First your x-axis is `continuous`, as @Axeman already mentioned in the comments. I would suggest using the `facet_row` of `ggforce`, because this will also show the y-axis of your second plot like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

df %>%        
  ggplot(aes(x = score)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Score", breaks = 0:8) +
  ggforce::facet_row(vars(damage), scales = 'free', space = 'free')
```

Output:

[image]

If you use the `facet_grid`, it doesn't show the labels for your second histogram like her:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

df %>%        
  ggplot(aes(x = score)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Score", breaks = 0:8) +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(damage), scales = 'free', space = 'free')
```

Output:

[image]