# How do I get the ggplot objects back from an arrangeGrob object

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, ggplotly

I have a function that returns an `arrangeGrob`. I would like the access the individual ggplot objects to make them an input to say ggplotly. I tried looking at the structure of the arrangeGrob object, but there doesn't seem that there is a way to get that. I don't need to plot the plot I need to use it elsewhere. In the example below, I'd like to be able to get back each of the (ggplot) p1 in the list  given to arrangeGrob.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
p1 = ggplot(data = pressure, aes(x = temperature, y = pressure)) + geom_line() + theme_light()

p = arrangeGrob(grobs = list(p1, p1), ncol=2, widths=c(1,1))
str(p)
grid.draw(p)
grid.draw(p$grobs[[1]])
grid.draw(p$grobs[[2]])

str(p1)
str(p$grobs[[2]])
plot(p$grobs[[2]])

library(plotly)
ggplotly(p$grobs[[2]])
```

Comment: `p2` seems to be missing

Comment: regardless of ^^ try doing `p$grobs[[1]] ; ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))` and compare the output. The plots have been rendered and there's [no going back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499608/inverse-of-ggplotgrob)

Comment: @hrbrmstr p2 = p1 now

`p$grobs[[1]] ; ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))` are indeed the same. So there is no way to get the ggplto object back? that's dissapointing

Comment: Aye, but not unexpected due to the fact that since it is rendered all context is gone (no data, no factors, groups, etc).

Comment: @hrbrmstr what is the reason anyone would want to return a grob instead of a ggplot object?

Comment: To use it in other `grid` graphics context (ggplot2 isn't the only package that uses `grid`) or even as an object in a ggplot2 plot itself (you can annotate a plot with an arbitrary grob)

Comment: And it's lighter, isn't it? That's the only price I would pay for information loss.

Comment: oh yes. pre-gtable objects come with all the data frames too. can be pretty large

Answer (score 0):

not sure why you'd want to do this but you can easily fool arrangeGrob's simple class check and delay the conversion to a grob to drawing time,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

p1 = ggplot()

pl <- lapply(list(p1, p1), function(p) {class(p) <- c('dummy','grob'); p})

drawDetails.dummy <- function(x, recording = FALSE) {
  class(x) <- c('ggplot')
  grid.draw(ggplotGrob(x))
}

g = arrangeGrob(grobs = pl, widths=c(1,2))
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)

pp1 <- g$grobs[[1]]
class(pp1) <- class(p1)
identical(p1,pp1)
```

Comment: because i want to edit it. Also see my question. I explicitly say I want to use the objects as inputs to  ggplotly.