# R: Is it possible to extract the original data from a gtable object created with grid.arrange and ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid, gridextra, grob

#### Problem description

I have created an `gtable` (also `gTree`  `grob`  `gDesc`) object `myobj` via `myobj <- gridExtra::grid.arrange(g1,g2)` from two `ggplot` objects `g1`,`g2` some time ago and now I have to restore the data that I have used to create both ggplots. Is there a way to do this properly?

#### What I've tried so far

I have already tried to convert `myobj` using various functions, e.g., `ggpubr::as_ggplot`, resulting in an object with a `waiver()` as `$data` entry - so no success there - and I have also swept all the `grobs` entries in `myobj` where I in fact found the data points in the plot (looking like this

```
grobs.grobs.children.geom_point.points.5415.x1 
                                    0.04545455
```

), which are, however, only the position coordinates $\in (0,1)$ w.r.t. the corresponding axis. Then I probably can get the axis + the axis range and then extrapolate the original data points. But that seems excessively laborious. Is there a more simple solution to this?

#### Reprex (sort of)

Not sure if this actually results in the same object as I have (because mine is almost 2y old), but for a start:

```
library(ggplot)

# plot 1
g1 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(cols = vars(cyl))

# plot 2
g2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, colour = factor(cyl))) + geom_point() + facet_grid(vars(cyl))

# create object
myobj <- gridExtra::grid.arrange(g1, g2, ncol=1)

# Now I would need some extract_data function to retrieve mpg and mtcars:
list_with_mpg_and_mtcars <- extract_data(myobj)
```

Comment: Seems relevant: [Inverse of ggplotGrob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499608/inverse-of-ggplotgrob)

Comment: Thx. I have tried the functions / hacks suggested, I am only able to get to the point where my object is a proper looking `gg` or `ggplot` object but still with a `waiver()` as `$data` argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't; at this stage (namely, after `ggplotGrob`) the data have been processed into graphical objects and the mapping isn't usually reversible, much like an omelette.

If you are *desperate* for getting some values back you can inspect individual grobs corresponding to the plotted points, e.g.

```
myobj$grobs[[2]]$grobs[[2]]$children[[3]][c('x','y')]

$x
 [1] 0.525145067698259native 0.587040618955513native
 [3] 0.525145067698259native 0.89651837524178native 
 [5] 0.819148936170213native 0.954545454545455native
 [7] 0.474854932301741native 0.699226305609285native
 [9] 0.648936170212766native 0.819148936170213native
[11] 0.470986460348163native

$y
 [1] 0.233037353850445native  0.435264173310709native 
 [3] 0.425966388507938native  0.205143999442133native 
 [5] 0.0691638967016109native 0.12030171311685native  
 [7] 0.266741823760489native  0.143546175123777native 
 [9] 0.191197322237977native  0.0454545454545455native
[11] 0.339961879082309native
```